# How to make each executor read or write from hbase?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

I tried to broadcast the connection, but I don't know how to solve the serialization problem.

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

messages.map(_._2).filter(_.length > 0).foreachRDD(rdd => {
  val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create
  hbaseConf.set("hbase.rootdir", "hdfs://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/hbase")
  hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "Master,slave1,slave2")
  val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConf)

  val hbaseBr = ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(connection)
  rdd.foreach(x => {
    DataHandlingUtil.dataHandle(x, nameMap, dictBroadcast, platformMapBr, hbaseBr.value)
  })
})

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Why `foreach`? Why not write RDD directly?

Comment: because I also need to save data to redis, read data from hbase and finally write data back to hbase.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for this code to make each executor create connection:

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    val connection = createNewConnection()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    connection.close()
  }
}
```

Better version :

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    // ConnectionPool is a static, lazily initialized pool of connections
    val connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection)  // return to the pool for future reuse
  }
}
```

Note: Copied the above code from Spark streaming programming guide : https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html

Another choice is to use HBaseContext which has bulkGet, bulkPut, bulkDelete methods built in.

Here is a sample code:

```
val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
hbaseConf.set(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, "hbase_URL")
hbaseConf.setInt(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT, 2181)
implicit val hbaseC = new HBaseContext(new SparkContext(new SparkConf()), hbaseConf)
```

A line about HBaseContext : At the root of all Spark and HBase integration is the HBaseContext. The HBaseContext takes in HBase configurations and pushes them to the Spark executors. This allows us to have an HBase Connection per Spark Executor in a static location.

For more details, go to this link https://hbase.apache.org/book.html